# Adding New Role in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have added new role in functions.php file by this code:

```
// Add a custom user role

$result = add_role( 'supplier_for_planvent', __(
'Supplier_For_Planavent' ),


array(

    'read' => true, // true allows this capability
    'edit_posts' => true, // Allows user to edit their own posts
    'edit_pages' => true, // Allows user to edit pages
    'edit_others_posts' => true, // Allows user to edit others posts not just their own
    'create_posts' => true, // Allows user to create new posts
    'manage_categories' => true, // Allows user to manage post categories
    'publish_posts' => true, // Allows the user to publish, otherwise posts stays in draft mode

));
```

But when I log-in through new role account, I got this message:

You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

I dont like using plugins for simple stuff, but i always prefer using plugins for user roles as sometimes it becomes very tricky. Try using "User Role Editor".